How could I fuzzy search completions?
Suppose I want to insert px-10 but I don't recall the exact form of this expression. This is an available completion for tailwind css. Suppose I recall the expression begins with p, then some letter, then it continues with -. Other similar expressions, available as tailwind css completions, are py-10, ps-10, pt-10, pb-10, etc. What could I fuzzy search/query to find that px- is a possible completion?

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Are you using vanilla Vim or some LSP bridge plugin like coc.nvim?

@VivianDeSmedt am using nvim-cmp
